# QueryableExtensions for ValueInjecter

Tags: automapper, automapping, valueinjecter

Does anything like [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions.cs) for Automapper exist for ValueInjecter?

For those unfamiliar with this [functionality](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/02/09/autoprojecting-linq-queries/) it allows for the automatic projection of properties to be performed for linq queries so that only the needed columns are selected from the database when projecting an entity to a simple DTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need only the needed property getters to be called, try the **SmartConventionInjection**, this injection will only get the value of the property when it's needed, it also remembers the matching properties between types so that next time it will work faster

https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SmartConventionInjection&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm after, specifically. The idea is to perform a projection against an IQueryable source such that only the needed properties to perform the injection are selected from the datasource. I want to avoid selecting all of the columns for a complex domain model that is being projected against a very simple DTO.

Comment: the IQueryable bit is a collection so you do a foreach loop yourself for this, and at each iteration you use the injection `dto.InjectFrom<SmartInj>(entity)`, the lazy loading with EF for instance gets activated when you try to get the property, so if the getter is not called the DB won't be hit for that.

I recommend you to just try it and you'll see if you have what you want